# How to make 4 items in a row using while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display my products from the database. I'm trying to split it using the if 4%=0, but I can't get it to display 4 items in a row.

**Here is my codes:**

```
<table>
<tr>
     <?php
        include "connect_to_mysql.php";
        $split = 0;
        $display_all = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products 
            ORDER BY FIELD(category, 'ipad','iphone','others')");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($display_all)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $product_code = $row['product_code'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $split++;   
        if ($split%4==0){
        echo '</tr><tr>';   
        }
        ?>
        <td>
        <table class="normal_text" align="center">
        <tr>
        <td><a href="product.php?product_id=<?php echo $id?>">
            <img width="200px" height="133px" src="products/<?php echo $product_code?>.jpg" />
            </a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" style="font-weight:bold"><?php echo $title;?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center">$<?php echo $price;?></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: that's because you are crating a table inside each cell

Comment: @Chasing Death how should I code it??

Comment: Check my answer. You need to start `<tr>` with `%4==0` and end it with `%4==3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the PHP logic *before*, rather than *inside* your HTML table output.
Try reorganizing like this:

```
<?php
include "connect_to_mysql.php";
$split = 0;
$display_all = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products 
    ORDER BY FIELD(category, 'ipad','iphone','others')");
?>
<table class="normal_text" align="center">
<tr>
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($display_all)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $product_code = $row['product_code'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $price = $row['price'];

    // output product details -- note use of quotes to include PHP vars
    $rowHTML = "<td><a href='product.php?product_id=$id'>";
    $rowHTML .= "<img width='200px' height='133px' src='products/$product_code.jpg' />";
    $rowHTML .= "</a><br/>";
    $rowHTML .= "<strong>$title</strong>";
    $rowHTML .= "$price</td>";
    echo $rowHTML;

    $split++;   
    if ($split%4==0){
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Now the items can appear 4 in a row. But the title and price are on the right instead of being at the bottom of the image.

Comment: Instead of putting the $title and $price in a <td>, you can include them in the same table cell and add a <br/> after the image.  I edited the answer to show you how.

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($display_all)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $product_code = $row['product_code'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $price = $row['price'];
    if ($split % 4 === 0) echo "\n<tr>";
?>
```

> > // ONLY `<td>` CODE `</td>` here. NO `<tr>` and NO `</table>`

```
<?php
 if ($split % 4 === 3) echo "</tr>"; 
  $split++;
 }
?>
```

You are starting and ending  at same time and then putting table for each.
You want to start `<tr>` when `%4==0` and end `</tr>` when `%4==3`.

Comment: but how do I code it so that the title and price will be display at the bottom of the product? without using <tr>

Answer (score -1):

Rather than use modulus (`%`), just add a second variable called `$cols`, assign it to the amount of columns you want, and compare it. For example:

```
    $rows = 1;
    $cols = 4;

    $display_all = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY FIELD(category, 'ipad','iphone','others')");

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($display_all)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $product_code = $row['product_code'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $price = $row['price'];
    $split++;   
    if ($rows==$cols){
        echo '</tr><tr>'; 
        $rows = 1;
    }
```